# Bounding box/region proposal method for multiple line plots

Tags: python, image, image-processing, time-series, bounding-box

Given an image like this how can I segment them into separate sub-images?
That is I am looking for a method to propose bounding regions for non overlaping time series. Please point me to the right search terms, scientific papers.

[image]

**EDIT** assume no color assumptions.

**EDIT2** Example image

How can I segment out each signal (line plot)? Last two signals overlap in the beginning, thus I cannot make an assumption that there is a spacing between signals.

My current approach involves computing blobs, and finding min distance between each pair of blobs. I then merge blobs based on distance threshold. But there are multiple issues: choice of threshold, stopping criterion.

[image]

Comment: If you want to extract the red and green lines, you could look for pixels with those given colors. It should be fairly straight-forward. You're unlikely to find scientific papers about this, it's a trivial problem. I would look for a good book on image processing. The tag wiki for [tag:image-processing](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/image-processing/info) has some pointers.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I do not have any color assumptions.

Comment: Do you mean that colors differ from graph to graph? What else differs?

Comment: Yes, the colors might be different. So color agnostic method is preferable.

Comment: blob detection will work as long as the graphs don't touch anything

Comment: If all the graphs are similar, rather than detecting the lines, removing the axes may be easier. Once you are left with just 2 lines, then everything is easier

Comment: @Piglet what is a good way to merge blobs that belong to the same plot? In my case the line plot has multiple discontinuities, thus resulting in multiple blobs.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I do remove axes and everything else as part of preprocessing.